# Django - Rendering Dict values to Template takes more time

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I am having dictionary of around 50 key-value pair.

I tried to render this my my template.

```
** Some Operations here **
temp={...........}  // It has 50 pairs
return render_to_response(
    'tr/page.html',
    tempContentRes,
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
)
```

In Template file tr/page.html am using the dict values to some textbox, and some charts .

for example

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ am }}" name="album" />
```

I have set the time difference in view page the all operation in view takes less than a sec.

The problem is, rendering html takes about 2 minutes.

Sample content in my dict:

```
temp = {
    'price_range': ['[4,0],[3,0],[2,0],[1,10],[0,0]', '[4,0],[3,2],[2,0],[1,0],[0,0]', '[4,0],[3,0],[2,0],[1,1],[0,0]'],
    'List': u'<li><a href="/dashboard/performance/?store=Play_list">Play_list</a></li><li><a href="/drd/page/?sre=Road">Road</a></li><li><a href="/drd/page/?sre=Sify">Sify</a></li><li><a href="/drd/page/?sre=Youtube">Youtube</a></li>',
    'PlaysCount': 14L,
    'trc': [u'12345678', u'123456789', u'1234567'],
    'tbCount': 15L,
    'rdePer': 0,
    'rylist': {'ca': 1, 'gb': 11, 'se': 2},
    'topCount': 57L,
    # .......
}
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure all the dictionary keys and values are actually *values*, not placeholders (e.g. [lazy properties](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lazy)) for an expensive computation? Also, your example does not seem to actually use `temp` variable - could you please post actual code (with 50 key-value pairs collapsed) that is used to render the page.

Comment: so if you render the template without passing the dictionary, then it's fast? Could you provide any example what's in the dictionary? Also a bit advanced topic: why dont you use django form for rendering the inputs? It will save you a lot of time.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Yes, without dict it takes 3sec to load a template

Comment: Could you please see my edits here

Comment: it seems very unlikely rendering such dictionary would take 2 minutes. You can add `from time import time; print time()` after each line to see if rendering the template is really the slow thing. If so, I'd expect there's some kind of recursive loop. Having the code of your template here would help.